# Uitablecell pushing into different nibs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Hello I am trying to push different nibfiles into view
When you click On the uitablecell it corresponds to.
I have no Idea where to start.

Comment: Start from reading some documents? relevant classes and protocols: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. Even built-in Navigation based application template has functionality you want - you can get basic idea from it.

Comment: This ques is similar to already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102122/how-can-i-move-to-another-view-controller-when-the-user-clicks-on-a-row/5102284#5102284 first try to search then ask here

Answer (score 2):

Read UITableView class and navigation based app and see this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  //and code like this

   if(indexPath.row==0)
   {
     FirstController *objFirstController=[[[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objFirstController animated:YES];
   }
else
{
   SecondController *objSecondController=[[[SecondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondController animated:YES];
 }
}
```