# Push different ViewControllers for every cell in a sectioned UITableView

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView with sections for different alphabets. I want each cell to push a different ViewController. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Storyboard, Control drag from each cell to the the ViewController you want it to attach. Make the segue type to "Push"

Answer (score 0):

If your using storyboards, here's a possible solution: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1274743

Comment: [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102122/how-can-i-move-to-another-view-controller-when-the-user-clicks-on-a-row ]